# In DNA replication, are there phosphodiester bonds in the primer ? between the RNA nucleotides before being replaced

Tags: dna-replication

When hydrogen bonds happen between the RNA nucleotide bases and the DNA bases , do phosphodiester bonds form between the RNA nucleotides in the primer ? 
No source I read is clear about this, are their bonds between the RNA nucleotides ?

Comment: @Dirigible — I suspect that the poster is talking about Okazaki fragments, and wishes to know whether they are covalently linked to the growing DNA. If so, I seem to recall a similar question previously. However the question is unclear. Poster, please clarify your question and preferably present a diagram, or link to one, so we can see what aspect seems unclear to you. The accompanying text would help — it could be that rather than the texts being unclear, there is something in the explanation you are misunderstanding.

Comment: I have posted an answer. However, this seems like a basic question and is easily answered by consulting sources such as Wikipedia. As such I'm flagging this question as ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) since it "addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals". ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score -2):

A [primer](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/primer-305/) is by definition a short single strand of nucleic acid (i.e. a series of nucleotides linked together by phosphodiester bonds). See also [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primer_(molecular_biology)]).